# MergeProjectDex of Android Gradle Plugin 7.2 takes extra five hours with Jacoco coverage compilation

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, jacoco

MergeProjectDex of Android Gradle Plugin 7.2 takes extra five hours with Jacoco coverage compilation, has anyone encountered this problem?

I have tried many versions（agp 7.0～7.2）,none of them solve this problem, can anyone share their optimization experience and solutions?